# Angular 8 - Typescript - Catch data in an error from a subscribe and not only the header

Tags: angular, typescript

This is a strange case. I am subscrying to a service, and the code is something like this:

> ```
> this.externalService.observableMethod(request).subscribe( 
>    response => {
>       (...)
>    }, error => {
>       console.log("Error: ", error)
>    }
> )
> ```

The problem is that sometimes the service (which is a dependency that i install) is sending me the data as an error! i know its not a problem that i should solve here, but i dont owe the service and they should repair it in some time.
I am using chrome, if i check the console i see that its showing me the header of the json. But if i go to Network tool and see the response of my call, i see that the json is having the data that i need.

For example, this is the structure of the json i see in the Network:

```
{
   "header": 
      {
         "messageCode":"HTTP200",
         "messageDescription":"OK",
         "resultCode":"fail"
       },"data": 
      {
        //the info that i need
      }
}
```

I thought: "ok, despite the error i can take the info in my code with something like error.data". But thats my problem, the error is not the entire json, its only the header.
In the example code from above, the Console of chrome is showing me:

Error:
{
"messageCode":"HTTP200",
"messageDescription":"OK",
"resultCode":"fail"
}

I dont know if there is something that i can do, but i wanted to ask if someone has face a problem like that. Who knows

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: That's a tough case, considering you do not own the service. Without knowing much of your code, I cannot write an answer, but I suggest you try to solve it with a `HttpInterceptor`. If you are lucky, you can read the data in there, and add it to the header part

Comment: Thanks Poul! luckly, the service's team resolve the issue. But i didn't know this, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing something like

```
    this.externalService.observableMethod(request)
    .pipe(map(obj=>{
      return obj.data ? obj.data : obj; // in exception case scenario you will have data in your json.
})). subscribe() // normal response can be processed.
```

Comment: Thanks maxkart for the answer. Luckly, the team of the service solve the issue. I try this way but didn't work anyway :S